# How to get the first n elements of string sequence with split.take? VB .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, split, autocad, take

I created a .dll plugin for both AutoCAD and CIVIL 3D.

I'm trying to retrieve the first elements of these sequences:

"Autodesk AutoCAD 2019 - [Drawing 1]" I just want to obtain "Autodesk AutoCAD 2019" (I want first 3 elements)
and
"Autodesk CIVIL 3D 2019 - [Drawing 1]" I just want to obtain "Autodesk CIVIL 3D 2019". (I want first 4 elements)

I obtain these sequences by using `Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowTitle` which is retrieving the window title of the application I'm using at the moment.

However, sometimes I'm using AutoCAD, others I'm using CIVIL 3D and I want to retrieve their application names as strings, displayed in a message box, telling me which application I'm using at the moment.

I have tried with:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowTitle.Substring(0, 22)
```

but this one is not reliable for when I display the message box at the start of autocad or when closing. It only works if I display the message box in between start and closing.

I think I should try with:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowTitle.Split.Take(4)
```

or

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowTitle.Take(4)
```

but I can't seem to get it to work despite already trying to understand it (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/return-or-skip-elements-in-a-...).

How should I do it with Take???

Many Thanks!

Comment: Um, don't you actually just want whatever comes before the dash?  If so then the logical thing to do is get the index of the dash and then get the substring up to that index.  Either that or just split on the dash and get the first substring.  You might then want to `Trim` the result.

Comment: @gmcilhinney
Thanks. That's a great ideia.
How exacly is it ?
I've tried:
Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowTitle.Substring(0, IndexOf("-"))
but I must be doing something wrong

Comment: You have to call `IndexOf` on the `String` containing the character you want to find the index of.  Get the `MainWindowTitle` and assign it to a variable, then use that variable as much as you need, i.e. call `IndexOf` and `Substring` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
Dim originalString As String = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowTitle

Dim splittedString As String() = originalString.Split("-".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Dim productName As String = splittedString(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use `Take` then you have to make sure that you provide it with the correct input.  If you do that then it will provide the correct output.  Do you actually know what those inputs and outputs are?  The input is an `IEnumerable(Of T)` and the output is another `IEnumerable(Of T)` that contains either the specified number of items or all the items from the original list, which ever is smaller.

This is obviously wrong:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowTitle.Take(4)
```

because `MainWindowTitle` is a `String` so that means that your input will be an `IEnumerable(Of Char)` so you'll just be getting the first four characters in the string.  This looks more promising:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowTitle.Split.Take(4)
```

Have you actually checked that `Split` returns what you think it does?  When code does work as you expect, NEVER assume anything.  Check.

By the way, `Split` is a method, not a property.  You don't have to use parentheses on a method call when providing no arguments but you're doing it for `GetCurentProcess` so why would you then not for `Split`?  Inconsistency is always bad.  Decide what you're going to do and do it in every case.  Personally, I always include parentheses on a method call whether there are arguments or not, for clarity.  I don't use them on constructors without arguments though, because it can be confused with array creation at a glance.

Anyway, as I said, if `Split` returns the correct input then `Take` will provide correct output.  The question is, do you know what to do with that output?  What for do you want it in?  An `IEnumerable(Of T)` needs to be enumerated to be of any use and exactly how you do that depends on exactly what you want to end up with.  For instance, if you want to reconcatenate those substrings back into a `String` with spaces between them then you would call `String.Join` and pass the list as the second argument.  Of course, if you were going to do that then you'd be better off with my other suggestion, i.e. `IndexOf` and `Split`.

Comment: I always check. Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowTitle.Split.Take(4) doesn't work because I'm getting Take's arguments wrong. Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowTitle.Split also doesn't work for the same reason, its missing something. I've read about Split and Split.Take and Take. But I don't quite get it (I'm new to VB).

Comment: There's no such thing as `Split.Take`.  There is the `String.Split` method, which splits a `String` into an array of substrings on one or more delimiters.  There is the `Enumerable.Take` method, which takes a generic enumerable list and returns a generic enumerable list of the same type containing up to the specified number of items from the beginning of the input.

Comment: How about you stop being so vague?  What EXACTLY does `MainWindowTitle` return?  Is that what you expect and, if not, how does it differ?  If so, what does `Split` return?  Is that what you expect and, if not, how does it differ?  If so, what does `Take` return?  Is that what you expect and, if not, how does it differ.  We're not psychic.  You have to provide us with the relevant information.  To say that something "doesn't work" is never, EVER sufficient.  You need to specify EXACTLY what you expect to happen and what actually does happen.

Comment: The `Split` method will split on whitespace characters if you provide no arguments so what you're doing should work fine.  The way you're calling `Take` looks fine too, based on what information you have provided.  I suspect that you just don't know how to use an `IEnumerable(Of T)` but that's only a guess because you haven't provided a proper description of the issue.

Comment: I did say it in my question.

MainWindowTitle retrieves:

"Autodesk AutoCAD 2019 - [Drawing 1]"

or 

 "Autodesk CIVIL 3D 2019 - [Drawing 1]"

But I wanted it to retrieve:

"Autodesk AutoCAD 2019"

or

 "Autodesk CIVIL 3D 2019"

Comment: The reason I say that is because, based on your OP, you seem to think that you can replace an expression that returns a `String` with an expression that returns a `IEnumerable(Of String)`, which you very much can't.

Comment: **"I did say it in my question"**.  Um, did you notice how I asked more questions after that?  If I have drag information out of you kicking and screaming then I'll give up very soon.  Provide a FULL and CLEAR description of the problem.  I will contribute nothing further until you do.

Comment: Thanks. The issue is that I'm new to VB and I don't even know how to write a single line of code. It's a steep learning curve and I just started last week.

Comment: As I said, I'm new to VB, sorry if I couldn't provide a better description.

Comment: Sure, there's a lot to learn.  There's ways to learn it though.  My greatest peeve is the number of people who completely ignore the fact that VS has a Help menu and also provides context-sensitive help via the F1 key, as Windows has been doing for decades.  Have you used that to read the documentation for the `Split` and `Take` methods to see exactly how they work?  It won't always solve all your problems but it's something every developer should do first every time they need help.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've been using the Help and I read the pages of Split and Take, but I still couldn't get it right. Sorry. I'm not a developer. I'm an architect.

Comment: You could;, you just didn't.  You're not alone.  People tend not to think very hard about what other people might need to in order to help them.  For instance, if something "doesn't work" then there are three possibilities: you get a compilation error, you get a run time exception or you get an unexpected result.  All three of those are easy to relay to us.  Before asking for help, look at ALL the information available to you and ask yourself what of that would be helpful to us.  Error me4ssages and actual code behaviour are obviously in the helpful category.

Comment: I'll do that next time. Thank you